# how to call android settings from my app shared preference screen

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a shared preferences file in my android app.
In my preferences file (xml) I have number of CheckBoxPreferences.
I want to add antother preference, so that when the user presses on it 
he wil get the android location preferences (gps).

I tried to add this to my pref file:

```
 <Preference xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:key="pref_key_gpsStatus"
        android:title="Gps Settings" />
```

and to try catch it on the onPreferenceClick and onSharedPreferenceChanged
and call the gps setting by intent:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
```

when I clicked on the preference nothing happend.

the other thing I tried is in the xml file:

```
<Preference xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:key="pref_key_gpsStatus"
    android:title="Gps Settings" />


    <intent 
        android:action="android.settings.WIRELESS_SETTINGS"/>
```

and.. still nothing happend.

someone have an idea?

thanks!

this is the full pref.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<CheckBoxPreference
    android:defaultValue="true"
    android:key="@string/pref_key_shakeSense"
    android:summaryOff="@string/shakeOff"
    android:summaryOn="@string/shakeOn"
    android:title="@string/shakeSence" />

<CheckBoxPreference
    android:defaultValue="true"
    android:key="@string/pref_key_locationViewShots"
    android:summaryOff="@string/displayOff"
    android:summaryOn="@string/displayOn"
    android:title="@string/locationViewShots" />

<CheckBoxPreference
    android:defaultValue="true"
    android:key="@string/pref_key_sound"
    android:summaryOff="@string/soundOff"
    android:summaryOn="@string/soundOn"
    android:title="@string/speakUserLocation" />

<CheckBoxPreference
    android:defaultValue="false"
    android:key="@string/pref_key_Zoom"
    android:summaryOff="@string/notActive"
    android:summaryOn="@string/active"
    android:title="@string/autoZoom" />

<Preference 
    android:key="pref_key_gpsStatus"
    android:title="Gps Settings" />
    <intent android:action="android.settings.WIRELESS_SETTINGS"/>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this snippet, the intent is outside of the preference.

```
<Preference xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:key="pref_key_gpsStatus"
    android:title="Gps Settings" />


<intent android:action="android.settings.WIRELESS_SETTINGS"/>
```

You should enclose it as part of the preference:

```
<Preference xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:key="pref_key_gpsStatus"
    android:title="Gps Settings" >


    <intent android:action="android.settings.WIRELESS_SETTINGS"/>

</Preference>
```